# Joining three tables and using a left outer join

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have three tables.  Two of them join equally but one will need to join with a left.  I'm finding a lot of code to do this in linq but between two tables only.

Here is the SQL code that I'm trying to re-code within LINQ.

```
   SELECT PRSN.NAME
       ,CO.NAME
       ,PROD.NAME
   FROM PERSON PRSN
     INNER JOIN COMPANY CO ON PRSN.PERSON_ID = CO.PERSON_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT PROD ON PROD.PERSON_ID = PROD.PERSON_ID;
```

Here is a snippet of LINQ code that I'm using as a base.  I'm just not able to piece together the third table (product in my sample SQL) via LINQ and with a left outer join.  The sample is between two tables.  Thanks for any tips.

```
   var leftOuterJoinQuery =
    from category in categories
    join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID into prodGroup
    from item in prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new Product{Name = String.Empty, CategoryID = 0})
        select new { CatName = category.Name, ProdName = item.Name };
```

Michael

Answer (score 46, accepted):

How about this:

```
var loj = (from prsn in db.People
           join co in db.Companies on prsn.Person_ID equals co.Person_ID
           join prod in db.Products on prsn.Person_ID equals prod.Person_ID into prods
           from x in prods.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new { Person = prsn.NAME, Company = co.NAME, Product = x.NAME })
```

EDIT: if you want to do a left outer join on all tables, you can do it like this:

```
var loj = (from prsn in db.People
           join co in db.Companies on prsn.Person_ID equals co.Person_ID into comps
           from y in comps.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join prod in db.Products on prsn.Person_ID equals prod.Person_ID into prods
           from x in prods.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new { Person = prsn.NAME, Company = y.NAME, Product = x.NAME })
```

Comment: no worries, mate. I had the same problem recently... took a while to figure it out. happy to share :)

Comment: @Beno what do you do if you want to use left outer join on each table instead one inner and one outer join?

Comment: If second JOIN contain to db.Companies, how to refer to "co"?

Answer (score 6):

Taken from another Stackoverflow thread somewhere, there's a more legible way to do this:

```
   var loj = (from prsn in db.People
           from co in db.Companies.Where(co => co.Person_ID == prsn.Person_ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
           from prod in db.Products.Where(prod => prod.Person_ID == prsn.Person_ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new { Person = prsn.NAME, Company = co.NAME, Product = prod.NAME })
```

This uses a mix of linq query syntax and lambda syntax to what (I believe is) the best result. There's no copious re-aliasing of identifiers, and it's the most concise way to do this that I've seen.

Comment: This solution performed ten times slower for me, my setup is six tables each with 1000+ entries.